How to fit a custom UIView to Its parent SwiftUI view?
I’m working on a SwiftUI project where I need to integrate a custom UIKit view (PopoverListViewWithCreate). In UIKit, I can easily add this view to my ViewController by changing the class of a UIView in the storyboard and setting its constraints to fill the screen (leading, trailing, top, and bottom all set to zero). This works perfectly in UIKit.
However, when I attempt to use PopoverListViewWithCreate in a SwiftUI view, it appears centered on the screen and is too small. I need to ensure that PopoverListViewWithCreate fits itself to the parent SwiftUI view correctly.
Current Setup:
I have a PopoverListViewWrapper that acts as a coordinator for the custom UIView.
import SwiftUI

struct PopoverListViewWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var items = [ListViewItem]()
    var tag: Int
    var selectedId: Int64
    var enableDelete: Bool
    var title: String

    class Coordinator: NSObject, PopoverListViewDelegate {
        var parent: PopoverListViewWrapper
        
        init(_ parent: PopoverListViewWrapper) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func didSelectItem(id: Int64) {
            
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PopoverListViewWithCreate {
        let uiView = PopoverListViewWithCreate()
        uiView.initialize(sender: context.coordinator)
        uiView.can(addNew: true)
        uiView.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return uiView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PopoverListViewWithCreate, context: Context) {
        uiView.loadData(items: items, tag: tag, selectedId: selectedId, enableDelete: enableDelete)
        uiView.updateTitle(title: title)
    }
}

and this is the UIView for testing the popover screen:
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var showPopover: Bool = false
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            Button(action: {
                showPopover = true
            }) {
                Text("Tap me")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.leading, .trailing, .bottom])
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: showPopover) {
            PopoverListViewWrapper(
                items: viewModel.locations,
                tag: viewModel.locationsTag,
                selectedId: 0,
                enableDelete: true,
                title: "Downloads"
            )
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

Problem:
I want to keep PopoverListViewWrapper as it is but need guidance on how to ensure my custom UIView PopoverListViewWithCreate correctly sizes and positions itself to fit the parent view when used in a SwiftUI screen.
Expected Outcome:
Any advice on how to achieve this or examples of best practices for integrating UIKit views in SwiftUI while maintaining proper sizing would be greatly appreciated! I've tried some articles in Google and checked the other posts in stack overflow but none of them fixed my issue.

Please show a [mre] - include the implementation of PopoverListViewWithCreate.
